# Replace value after continuous same value in column

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
```

If I have n continuous ones (in this case n = 8), the gap between next continuous n ones is 4 zeros(I would like set up a rule eg: the gap between continuous number is m <=4 ), how can I replace those 4 zeros with 1?

My ideal out put would be like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'Fill_Gap': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})`

Only four zeros (at index 13-16) replaced by 1 cause they have 8 continuous 1 before and after.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: So all the groups but the last one will be set to 0?

Comment: The logic in my mind is: 1st step: check the count of continuous number. 2nd step: If there is 2 groups of continuous 1 but with a gap in the between, then count of the gap value. 3rd step: Replace the gap with the continuous value if the count of gaps is less then 4

Comment: You have two zeros (at index 3,4) between continous ones. Do you want those converted to ones, too? Please include your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for series of any length:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

#Check for runs of 8 (1's)
lst1=(df.shift(periods=0).A==1)
for x in range(1,8):
    lst1=lst1&(df.shift(periods=x).A==1)
    
#Check for runs of 4 (0's)
lst0=(df.shift(periods=0).A==0)
for x in range(1,4):
    lst0=lst0&(df.shift(periods=x).A==0)
    
#Get index
ones=np.array(list(lst1.index))[lst1]
zeros=np.array(list(lst0.index))[lst0]

#Fill Gaps
for x in list(range(1, len(ones))):
    if any(lst0[ones[x-1]:ones[x]]):
        lst1[ones[x-1]:ones[x]]=True
        
#Apply to data frame
df.loc[lst1, 'A']=1
```

---

Output:

```
    A
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  1
14  1
15  1
16  1
17  1
18  1
19  1
20  1
21  1
22  1
23  1
24  1
25  0
26  1
27  1
28  1
29  0
30  0
31  0
32  0
33  0
34  0
35  0
36  0
37  0
38  1
39  1
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) if you join the column into a string. With regex you can search for 4 zeros or less with `0{,4}` and lookbehind ... lookahead for 8 ones with `(?<=1{8})...(?=1{8})`. I don't think this is an efficient solution.

```
import re

df['fill_gap'] = df['A']
for i in re.finditer('(?<=1{8})0{,4}(?=1{8})', ''.join(df.fill_gap.astype('str'))):
    df.fill_gap.iloc[slice(*i.span())] = 1
df
```

Output

```
    A  fill_gap
0   1         1
1   1         1
2   1         1
3   0         0
4   0         0
5   1         1
6   1         1
7   1         1
8   1         1
9   1         1
10  1         1
11  1         1
12  1         1
13  0         1
14  0         1
15  0         1
16  0         1
17  1         1
18  1         1
19  1         1
20  1         1
21  1         1
22  1         1
23  1         1
24  1         1
25  0         0
26  1         1
27  1         1
28  1         1
29  0         0
30  0         0
31  0         0
32  0         0
33  0         0
34  0         0
35  0         0
36  0         0
37  0         0
38  1         1
39  1         1
```